# How to debug startup.cs of Azure App Service (breakpoints not being hit)?

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, asp.net-core

I have deployed an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project to Azure using an App Service.

There is a problem in `ConfigureServices()` in startup.cs (note: I know what the problem is, I'm trying to get the debugger to work and I pretend I don't know what's wrong).

I can attach the debugger using the Cloud Explorer and it will hit all breakpoints in my controllers just fine. However it completely ignores the ones in startup.cs.

I think the problem is that when the debugger attaches, the app has already been started. But I wonder: is there a way to get it to break in startup.cs?

Comment: I would suggest configuring application insights to get exception stack trace that will reveal the root cause of the issue

Comment: I have that on. But I'm explicitly trying to get the remote debugger to work.

Comment: Did you hit breakpoint in local bebug?

Comment: Well, yes. Set breakpoint, start debugging and it works.

Comment: I wonder if you ever got this working? I am trying to use Snapshot Debugger for "snapshot points" that are set in Startup.cs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-live-azure-applications?view=vs-2019